# Leftover kernel directories with files

Tags: files, linux-kernel

Why there are Kernel leftovers and can I get rid of them automatically?

---

There are so many kernel directories after a few months, that I get annoyed with it.

I just carefully inspected the `/usr/lib/modules` directory and removed all old kernel directories, but for one, and inspected its actual contents:

```
# \ls -lhkF 5.15.0-76-generic

total 28K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Aug 24 06:36 misc/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   45 Aug 24 06:36 modules.alias
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   12 Aug 24 06:36 modules.alias.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 24 06:36 modules.builtin.alias.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 24 06:36 modules.builtin.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 24 06:36 modules.dep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   12 Aug 24 06:36 modules.dep.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 24 06:36 modules.devname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   55 Aug 24 06:36 modules.softdep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49 Aug 24 06:36 modules.symbols
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   12 Aug 24 06:36 modules.symbols.bin
```

---

Inspecting the leftover files reveals they are empty or otherwise useless:

```
# for file in *; do [ -f $file ] && echo "$file": && cat --show-nonprinting $file && echo && echo; done

modules.alias:
# Aliases extracted from modules themselves.


modules.alias.bin:
M-0^GM-tW^@^B^@^A^@^@^@^L

modules.builtin.alias.bin:


modules.builtin.bin:


modules.dep:


modules.dep.bin:
M-0^GM-tW^@^B^@^A^@^@^@^L

modules.devname:


modules.softdep:
# Soft dependencies extracted from modules themselves.


modules.symbols:
# Aliases for symbols, used by symbol_request().


modules.symbols.bin:
M-0^GM-tW^@^B^@^A^@^@^@^L
```

---

Now, my question is, why these files are not being deleted by `apt-get --purge autoremove`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files don’t get removed by `apt-get autoremove --purge` because kernels are protected from auto-removal (see `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove`). You need to purge them periodically:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
for mods in /lib/modules/*/; do
    if ! [ -d "$mods"/kernel ]; then
        apt-get purge -y "linux-image-${mods##*/}"
    fi
done
```

Add that to a file in `/etc/cron.d/weekly` and you shouldn’t be troubled by left-over directories in `/lib/modules` again.

Answer (score 2):

The `misc/` directory is probably for some third-party modules (e.g. VirtualBox) whose management system apparently does not fully integrate with installation and removal of kernel versions.

To identify the module(s) in question, look into the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/misc` directory of your currently running kernel.

The `modules.*` files are all various module alias, dependency and symbol map files generated by the `depmod` command.

When a kernel package is removed, the package manager will automatically remove the modules packaged together with the kernel package (located in `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/kernel/`), but it will not touch any modules and module directories created by third-party module installers (like your `misc/`). If you use third-party modules managed by DKMS, it will normally place those modules into `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/updates/dkms/`, **and it will automatically remove those as the corresponding kernel package is removed.**

It looks like your third-party module management is a bit simplistic: it probably runs at boot time, checks that any existing `/lib/modules/<kernel version>/` directories have the `misc/` subdirectory and the third-party module(s) in them, and if any are missing, it will automatically build a version of the third-party module(s) for them, and runs `depmod <kernel version>` to ensure the dependencies of any third-party modules are processed correctly. But the part that would remove the modules and the `misc/` sub-directory for the removed kernel packages seems to be unimplemented or missing.

Since the files created by `depmod` appear to be updated even in directories from where the actual kernel package contents are actually removed, it seems the third-party module management script has simply looped through any existing `/lib/modules/<kernel version>` directories and still run `depmod` on each of them - resulting in empty or nearly empty `depmod` output files.

You might add a script like this to `/etc/kernel/postrm.d/` to hopefully get rid of this problem automatically (call it `zz-remove-miscmod` for example):

```
#!/bin/sh -e

version="$1"

# passing the kernel version is required
if [ -z "${version}" ]; then
    echo >&2 "W: zz-remove-miscmod: ${DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE:-kernel package} did not pass a version number"
    exit 0
fi

if [ -d "/lib/modules/$version/misc" ]; then
    rm -rf "/lib/modules/$version/misc"

    # uncomment to remove the modules.* files too, if necessary
    #rm -f "/lib/modules/$version/modules.*" 2>/dev/null || /bin/true

    # attempt to remove the kernel version module directory too,
    # in case it just became empty; if not, ignore the error
    rmdir "/lib/modules/$version" 2>/dev/null || /bin/true
fi
```

The script will automatically get executed just after a kernel package is removed, and will check for the presence of the `misc` sub-directory for the removed kernel version, and remove it. I'm assuming the `depmod`-created files are getting (re)produced at next boot; if I'm wrong, you could uncomment the `rm -f ...` line too.